# Gitlab Runner to open GUI on windows (Shell runner)

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I would need a GitLab Runner to open a program, in my case Unity3D and to start running a scene.
For this I selected a shell runner to run a batch script. The following code is executed successfully, but neither the window opens nor does the runner fail.

```
echo "Checkout branches"
git submodule update --init --remote
cd .\simulation\
git status
cd ..
cd .\agent\
git status
cd ..

echo "Open Unity3d"
"C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -openProject ".\simulation\Assets\Scenes\TestScene.unity"
```

Did I chose the wrong type or is it impossible to start GUI applications using GitLab Runner on Windows?

Best regards, Taka

Intention is that an AI agent is interacting with a Unity3d simulated environment

Comment: The gitlab-runner runs as a service with its own logon session. If it executes programs that open a GUI, you won't see it in your user logon session. So, it's probably working, you just can't see it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing the config.toml to use my user worked like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late. You should not start GitLab runner automatically in windows service. In Powershell you have to manually start the GitLab runner with `start gitlab-runner.exe` and then `run gitlab-runner.exe`